# Conducting a Proof Sequence - Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am having trouble conducting this proof sequence. Here are the premises:

p -> (q v r)

~q

~r

---

~p ^ ~ r

So far, I have this:

1. p -> (q v r) - Premise
2. ~q - Premise
3. ~r - Premise
4. ~(q v r) - implication, 1
5. ~q ^ ~r - De Morgan's Law, 4
6. ~r ^ ~q - commutativity, 5
7. ~r - simplification, 6
8. p -> (~r) - ???
9. ~p - Modus Tollens, 8, 3
10. ~p ^ ~r - conjunction, 9, 3

Is this sequence correct? I have a hard time understanding the use of implication and when/when not to apply it. My thoughts are using it whenever the disjunction is seen. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How do you get step 4? There seems to be a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't infer $\ {\sim}(q\,\vee r)\ $  from the first premise alone, as you try to do in step $4$ of your argument.  You can, however, infer $\ {\sim}q\,\wedge{\sim}r\ $ from the *second and third* premises by using [conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction), and you can *then* infer $\ {\sim}(q\,\vee r)\ $ from De Morgan's laws.

Your step $9$ is also incorrect.  Modus tollens doesn't allow you to infer $\ {\sim}p\ $ from $\ p\rightarrow{\sim}r\ $ and $\ {\sim}r\ $.  You *can*, however use modus tollens to infer $\ {\sim}p\ $ from *premise* $1$ and $\ {\sim}(q\,\vee r)\ $, and this latter proposition can be validly inferred from the premises in the way explained above.

Steps $7$ and $8$ of your argument are both valid but redundant, both because $\ {\sim}r\ $ is already a premise, and because these two inferences are only used for the invalid step $9$.

Step $10$ of your argument becomes a valid inference once you've replaced your invalid deduction of $\ {\sim}p\ $ with a valid one.  So, if you adopt the corrections suggested above, you'll get the following valid argument:

1. $\ p\rightarrow(q\vee r)\ $—premise.
2. $\ {\sim}q\hspace{4em}$—premise.
3. $\ {\sim}r\hspace{4em}$—premise.
4. $\ {\sim}q\,\wedge{\sim}r\hspace{1.5em}$—conjunction introduction, $2,3$.
5. $\ {\sim}(q\,\vee r)\hspace{1.5em}$—De Morgan's law, $4$.
6. $\ {\sim}p\hspace{4em}$—modus tollens, $1,5$.
7. $\ {\sim}p\,\wedge{\sim}r\hspace{1.5em}$—conjunction introduction, $6,3$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense. For future reference, when would it be valid to use implication if starting with a conditional statement? What I mean by this is, when is it valid to use implication starting with p -> (q v r)? Or is this idea never valid?

Comment: @roTenshi2  I don't understand what you mean by "use implication".  You could  say that my patchup of your argument uses implication in step $6$  when it applies the inference rule of modus tollens to infer ${\sim}p$ from $p\rightarrow p\vee q$ and ${\sim}(p\vee q)$.  The other common way that an argument can use implication is modus ponens—that is, the inference of a statement $\psi$ from the premises or prior inferences $\phi$ and $\phi\rightarrow\psi$.  If this doesn't cover what you mean by "use implication", then you'll need to be more clear  about  what you do mean.